# Lua multidimensional array __index metatable error

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua

I am trying to make dynamic multidimensional array, but i have a problem understanding how metatables work. It's like it has bug and it doesn't understand how to **get** and **set** a value. Here's an example:

```
function test(A)
  local G = {}
  local mt = {} 
  mt.__index = function(self, i)
    self[i] = setmetatable({}, mt)
    return self[i]
  end

  setmetatable(G, mt)

  G[1] = 10 -- adds 10
  G[1][2][3] = 10 -- error, why?breaks on G[1]

  --but when i do it like this
  G[1][2][3] = 10 -- adds 10
  G[1] = 10 -- erases whole table and adds 10   
  print(G[1][2][3]) -- error  
end
```

Comment: How `G[1][2][3] = 10` and `G[1] = 10` could coexist simultaneously in `G`?  What should be displayed by `print(G[1][2][3], G[1])`?

Comment: You are right! I am now trying with "__newindex" to place a table in G[1] so it can proceed on...Failing badly!

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what are you trying to achieve.  Should value `111` be overwritten or not in the following code: `G[1]=111; G[1][2][3]=222`?

Comment: I was trying to multi. matrices and through elimination get values...I have this problem where i want to understand, explore and make everything dynamical...thank you so much, I understand now why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `G[1]` to `10`. `10` is not a table, so there's no way `G[1][2][3]` can work.

FYI, `__index` is only invoked when the key points to `nil`. If `G[1] == 10`, then `G[1][2]` cannot invoke `__index`.

---

I suspect that you believe `G[1][2][3]` and `G[1]` are two completely separate entities. They are not. When you write:

```
G[1][2][3] = 42
```

...it's parsed as:

```
((G[1])[2])[3] = 42
```

In other words, in table `G`, you *access* index 1, then in that table, you *access* index 2, then in that table, you *assign to* index 3.

Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: I add "mt.__newindex = function(self, i, v) local m = {v} rawset(self, i, m) end" then G[1] = "10" passed, print(G[1][1]) printed "10", G[1][2][3] = 10 error, breaks on G[1][2]. What is going on?

Comment: If all you want is a dynamic, multi-dimensional table, then your original `__index` metamethod should work fine without a `__newindex`, so I'm still not sure what you expect Lua's behavior to be. When you point out errors, you should also tell us how you expect it to behave. (That's what Egor's comments are trying to get at.)

Comment: I was trying to multi. matrices and through elimination get values and I wanted to go full retard. Thank you so much, your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> G[1][2][3] = 10 -- error, why?breaks on G[1]

It's breaks on `G[1][2]`, because G[1] is number, not table.
Try proxy table: http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html
`__index` are fallback.